# 403 error when multiple statements state diff permission for same AWS resource in the same AWS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an AWS policy with an AWS resource (S3 bucket).
The policy as follows

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:Head*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/abc/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/def/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/pqr/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Head*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but when I try to retrieve object within this bucket from path `${bucket_name}/abc/abc/abc`

I clearly have given permission for this path,

but both permission have one change

```
permission 1: GET, LIST, HEAD
permission 2: GET, LIST
```

AWS Policy Simulation states, 2 statements applied and ListObject operation is allowed.

But in the program, I get a 403 error from AWS with an error message

```
Error when getting objectListing from S3: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Whats the prob here?

Comment: So your given policy is an S3 bucket policy, right? Which identity is accessing the S3 bucket? Are there any policies attached to the identity which is making the 'objectListing' call? If yes, are there any explicit denies in those policies?

Comment: other policies are applied but not on the same bucket , only this policy has this bucket reference

Comment: Another policy must not reference the bucket directly, it is enough if the user/role has a permission which contains Action:Deny for Action:S3:* on Resource> *. That explicit deny would override your Allow-Statement. That is why I am asking if there is a bucket policy and if yes, what the content of the s3 bucket policy (resource policy!!) is and whether there are other policies attached to the user.

Comment: @MartinLöper : I get it , but there is no other policy on the same resource or superceeding this policy , only this policy with 2 statements